# Okay to have singleton UIView subclass?

Tags: ios, uiview, singleton

I have a "loading..." overlay UIView subclass that is used in various places in my app.  The view always looks the same, and there should never be more than one being used at a time.  This seems like a good place to use a singleton.  For simplicity, I'd like to just have class methods `showOverlay` and `hideOverlay`, so that every class that uses it doesn't have to manage an instance of it.  It would just be duplicate code everywhere.

My instinct tells me it's a bad idea, but I'm not sure exactly why it would be.  Is it considered a bad practice?  It's a simple view that shouldn't take up much memory.

Comment: Is it costly to recreate? Would you really save code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No don't use a singleton for a `UIView`.
The best way to create a loading screen in very `UIViewController` is to create a super `UIViewController` like "ViewController".
There you create a public `showOverlay` and `hideOverlay` methode.

Then you need to sub-class al the `UIViewControllers` from `ViewController`

```
@interface ViewController

- (void)showOverlay;
- (void)hideOverlay;

@end

@interface MainViewController : ViewController

@end
```

In your implementatie implement the showOverlay and hideOverlay.
Then you can call these methodes from the `MainViewController`

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

> MBProgressHUD is an iOS drop-in class that displays a translucent HUD with an indicator and/or labels while work is being done in a background thread. The HUD is meant as a replacement for the undocumented, private UIKit UIProgressHUD with some additional features.

Comment: The project was using both MBProgressHUD and a custom overlay class when I started working on it.  The custom class was used in more places, and had additional functionality we needed, so I'm actually going thru and removing all the MBProgressHUDs.